# JPA Two primary key at owning side and One Foreign Key at the Child

Tags: jpa

I have 3 tables

Table name = TBL_USER
—Columns
SSN [PK]
Username[PK]
Password

Table name = TBL_ROLE
—Columns
Role_ID[PK]
Role_Name
Privilege

Table name = TBL_USER_ROLE
—Columns
Username [PK] [FK to TBL_USER]
Role_ID [PK] [FK to TBL_ROLE]

Is there any option to make the mapping :: [TBL_USER]—Username—[TBL_USER_ROLE]—Role_ID[TBL_ROLE]?

I tried to use

1. @CollectionTable with @ElementCollection along with creating an embeddable for TBL_USER_ROLE where User entity is the owner. However, it didn’t works because TBL_USER has 2 primary keys & TBL_USER_ROLE has only one column that represents the user. Hence, it breaks while using @JoinColumn
2. Tried to Create an entity for TBL_USER_ROLE with User entity as a variable, annotated with both @id and @ManyToOne annotation. This time it breaks, saying that UserRole entity has broken id. I think it is also due to multiple primary keys (SSN & Username) at the owning side [TBL_USER].